# Label Encoder causing numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoder

I want to perform IsolationForest algorithm on one of my dataset.
The libraries have been called, the csv files read and I only want to work with two column, so I only included those two column.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv', encoding='latin')
df=df[[‘numbers_column’, 'text_column']]
```

One of the columns has string/test so I was trying to use an encoder to turn it into numbers

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == "text_column":
        encoded= LabelEncoder()
        encoded.fit(df[col])
        df[col]=encoded.transform(df[col])
```

However, upon doing so I am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I have checked similar problems online, they examples are only when it comes to training and test data.

Comment: `df.columns` should be a valid call if you have the for loop starting right after the first two lines of code above. Otherwise, you've probably assigned `df` to some numpy array.

Comment: @akilat90, the ```for loop``` is just after the two lines of code

Comment: Add `print(type(df)` above the for loop and see the output - it should be pandas DataFrame